# My Jquery isn't "throwing" anything

Tags: jquery, html, codeigniter

I have a code here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>lib/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.hover-star').click(function (){
    $('.someDiv').text(this.val());
})
</script>



                <input name="neat" type="radio" class="hover-star" value="1" title="Poor"/>
                <input name="neat" type="radio" class="hover-star" value="2" title="Fair"/>
                <input name="neat" type="radio" class="hover-star" value="3" title="Satisfactory"/>
                <input name="neat" type="radio" class="hover-star" value="4" title="Outstanding"/>

                <div id="someDiv">aray</div>
```

My problem here is that it isn't throwing anything! I'm really in the corner here. In jsfiddle.net this is working. What I want is when my radio button is clicked it will show its value or title.

Comment: Your selector '.somediv' but in your html code there is '#someDiv'. It's and ID.

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles in your questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see four things in your code:

1. Don't forget the `;` at the end of your jquery click event definition.
2. You should use `#someDiv` instead of `.someDiv` as someDiv is an Object Id, not a Object class. This was already mentioned by Wesley.
3. You can't use `this.val()` since `val()` is not a native javascript function. You may want to use `$(this).val()` which is wrapping the javascript object into jQuery.
4. You need to use `$(function() { /* your code */ });` as your javascript function is defined before your HTML object will be created. This is a shortcut for 
   `$(document).ready(function () { /* your code */ });`

It would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $('.hover-star').click(function (){
    $('#someDiv').text($(this).val());
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I think you caught it: `this.val()` is the culprit. Not sure why OP said "this works on jsfiddle" with so many errors. I'm pretty sure the semicolon is optional though.

Comment: haha, your my SuperHero for today Wesley Murch. Got it working with your code. I'm pretty noob here in jquery. Also I am using star rating jquery.

Comment: Also last question. Is there a way to show the title of my radio input instead of its value? Or a condition where If $(this).val() == 1 return "Poor"; elseif $(this).val() == 2 return "Fair"; and so on.

Comment: Dean: try `$(this).attr('title');`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your jQuery code in the "ready" handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // put your jQuery code here.
});
```

Comment: do you mean I have to put it like this:'code'$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hover-star').click(function (){
    $('.someDiv').text(this.val());
})
});'/code'

Comment: Yes this is what I meant. In general, all your jQuery code should be within the "ready" handler - that way you are sure everything is properly loaded and initialized.

Comment: Ok., I'm able to see a dim light for now after I've added "ready" handler cause I tried to put an alert($(this).val()); and it works. But now  if I add this $('#someDiv').text(this.val()); it show me an error. It says that this.value is not a function.

Comment: "this" doesn't have a "val()" method - you are probably looking for `$('#someDiv').text($(this).val()); `. However, that doesn't really make sense - could you describe what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to output the value or title of my radio when click in my <div id='someDiv'></div>. E.g If I click radio1 it will show me its value which is 1 or much better the title: Poor and so on.

Comment: Then this should word: `var selectedValue = $('input:radio[name=neat]:checked').val();` That should give you the selected value.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$(this)`, not `this`.

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qaRsx/).